# Visual studio and SQL server licensing for app development

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, licensing

I am new to Visual Studio and .Net software development. Me with some of my friends are trying to develop a C#/WPF/MVC software with Visual Studio 2013 for a Windows desktop application. We will sell the software in market.

Kindly help me to understand the licensing questions:

1) Can we develop the software with VS Express or VS Developer edition? What license we need to buy from Microsoft for that?

2) We will need SQL Server 2012 to develop the software as it will have some queries. Do we need to buy SQL Server as well?

3) When the software will be installed, it will need SQL Server to access the data. So the customer will need to buy SQL Server to use the software and we can just sell our product with the queries?

Kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing

Comment: Thats why I have added licensing tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From Microsoft:

> Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be
>   used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms
>   provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for
>   Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the
>   Windows Store.

See this [link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

2) You can buy a license or use Express Edition at no charge, see this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), it depends on witch feature do you need. See this link for [SQL Server License](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29693)

3) Customer need to have SQL Server, maybe it can already have or it can download the express edition at no charge if your software doesn't need specific feature doesn't supported on express edition (see 2)

If DB is not shared between multiple installation of your product and DB is not very large you can also use [SQL Server Express LocalDB](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) same link of sql server previously mentioned.